# How to get a list of all (remote) database with the server name only?

Tags: c#, database-connection, connection-string

My requirement is to list all remote databases, but i only know the servername.

I am using below code, this works and returns all of the databases on localhost:

```
List<String> databases = new List<String>();
SqlConnectionStringBuilder connection = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
connection.DataSource = "localhost";
connection.IntegratedSecurity = true;
//connection.UserID = "";//
//connection.Password = "";//
String strConn = connection.ToString();
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
sqlConn.Open();
DataTable tblDatabases = sqlConn.GetSchema("Databases");
sqlConn.Close();
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in tblDatabases.Rows)
{
    String strDatabaseName = row["database_name"].ToString();
    databases.Add(strDatabaseName);
}
```

But how can i get databases on other servers without login informations?

Comment: Show the error including stacktrace. Your code is working for me with `connection.DataSource = "localhost"`. I get 8 databases.

Comment: please you can use other machine server.  it will throws the error.

Comment: _What_ error? You still haven't shown it. If you get an error that indicates that you can't login you have to provide the user and password.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Login failed for user 'ROOT\gokul.kandasamy'.

Comment: how to fix this error? I do not know your machine username , Password. Then how to get your database names. Please help

Comment: if you are not authorized to login you can't see the databases. So everything is working correctly. Are you really asking us how to list databases which you can't access?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123344/discussion-between-gokul-kumar-and-tim-schmelter).

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<string> GetDatabaseList()
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    string conString = "server=ServerName;uid=sa;pwd=Password;";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name from sys.databases", con))
        {
            using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: How can i  know the username , password for others machine?

Comment: Without username, password... you need to have windows authentication to access other machine's sql server. If you have, then change that into integrated security.

Comment: tried that method also. windows authentication took our system user, pwd. But other server names this method not working

Comment: yes. it wont't work.. you need to provide username and password to access their sql server (or) your username need permission to access it